# Akka & Case Statements

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka

I'm learning Akka for Scala, and have also been reading up on Scala's pattern matching/case statements.

In Akka, I can write an actor as follows:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
    def receive: Receive = {
        case msg: MyMsgClass => sender ! "message received!"
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this a case of Scala's pattern matching? If so, why is there no corresponding `match` keyword?
2. In the `case` line, is `msg` an identifier and is it required? What happens if I omit it and just use the class name (and presumably if I provide no identifier, I can't use the variable itself)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a case of pattern matching, in combination with a Partial Function. In short, the partial function

```
{
    case msg: MyMsgClass
}
```

only matches if there is an argument of type `MyMsgClass`. It handles a 'partial subset' of possible values. This syntax generates a `PartialFunction` object that handles the case where the input is a `MyMsgClass`.

You can also write:

```
{
    case MyMsgClass(value) => sender ! value
}
```

but in this case you only get the `value`. You can even do complex things like:

```
{
    case m @ MyMsgClass(AnotherClass(_), "this must be this string", a) => sender ! doSomething(m, a)
}
```

and it will nicely match only `MyMsgClass` objects that have a first parameter of type `AnotherClass` (regardless of its parameters, hence the `_`), the exact string `"this must be this string"`, and a value `a`. The `m @` syntax denotes that the object itself is also used, not just as a type.

Some more info: http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/10/scala-partial-functions-without-phd.html

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks. I see  the `Receive` type is a `PartialFunction`. Also: wow, so with this matching I could, for example, accept `Employee` with `Role` as `Manager`: `case emp @ Employee(Role.Manager)`?

Comment: @atc, exactly, if `Role.Manager` is an `object`, and `Employee`'s `unapply` method returns `Option[<Role.* type>]`, which is usually the case if `Employee` is a case class with the corresponding single argument.

Comment: I love it. Can you clarify on what happens if I omit the identifier? If I do `case MyClass => ...`, I can't then refer to the value itself? Only, perhaps, take the knowledge that I've an instance of `MyClass` somewhere? What about wildcard in this case?

Comment: Correct. You can only match the type in case, so this is great for triggering based on a message with no content (like `StartProcessing`). A wildcard, catch all could be done like `case _ => ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the Scaladocs for Actor that Receive is defined as having type:  type
Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit], which effectively means that it's an abstract member defined as being a partial function.